# How to update an .edmx File when the Database Location Changes (Entity Data Model Tools)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Could you explain me how change the connection string of edmx file without having to rebuild everythink?

For technical reason I need to move my dev database from my local computer to a professional server. I use MySQL. The transfer of the database has been done without any problem. The name of my schema changed from "MyProject" on my local computer to "MyProjectDatabase" on the server.

I also modified the connection string in my app.config.

```
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyProjectModel.csdl|res://*/MyProjectModel.ssdl|res://*/MyProjectModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=xx-xxxx-azure-xxx-x.cloudapp.net;user id=xxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;database=MyProjectDatabase&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now when I try to validate or update my model from database through Visual Studio the system want to recreate/add all my tables. I see nothing in my refresh tab. What should I do to tell my edmx file that my database is the same and he need to refresh, not to add tables?

--- FYI ---

I already followed the instructions of MSDN: [How to: Update an .edmx File when the Database Changes (Entity Data Model Tools)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but this link concerns a model update after the database schema has changed, not it's location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided concerns a model update after the database schema has changed, not it's location.

1. edmx->Metadata Artifact Processing->Copy to Output Directory
2. Remove schema definition files as application resources. Instead of `res://*/MyProjectModel.csdl` use `.\MyProjectModel.csdl`. Same for ssdl and msl.
3. Never worked with MySqlConnector, yet the `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` part at the end looks fishy. Provider was already specified as `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.

Comment: Yes I know the link I provided concerns a model update after the database schema has changed, not it's location. Your english is just better than mine to express this. I'll edit my question. Thank you for your help